# The transport failed to connect to the server error

Tags: email, vbscript

```
Set emailObj      = CreateObject("CDO.Message")

emailObj.Sender   = "zzz@xxx.com"
emailObj.To       = "xxx@xxx.com"

emailObj.Subject  = "Test CDO"
emailObj.TextBody = "Test CDO"

Set emailConfig   = emailObj.Configuration

emailConfig.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = "mail.live.com"
emailConfig.Fields("----/smtpserverport")   = 465
emailConfig.Fields("----/sendusing")        = 2  
emailConfig.Fields("----/smtpauthenticate") = 1  
emailConfig.Fields("----/smtpusessl")       = true 
emailConfig.Fields("----/sendusername")     = "xxxx@gmail.com"
emailConfig.Fields("----/sendpassword")     = "*****"

emailConfig.Fields.Update

emailObj.Send

If Err.Number = 0 Then 
  MsgBox "Done"
End If

If Err.Number <> 0 Then 
  MsgBox "Can't Proceed"
End If
```

It's a code to send email via live.com, but I am getting "The transport failed to connect to the server" error. Can anyone help me out in resolving this error?

Answer (score 1):

mail.live.com is just a webserver(farm):

```
xxx@iridium:~ $ nmap mail.live.com

Starting Nmap 6.47 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2016-03-31 08:53 CEST
Nmap scan report for mail.live.com (157.56.198.204)
Host is up (0.029s latency).
Other addresses for mail.live.com (not scanned): 157.55.230.252
rDNS record for 157.56.198.204: origin.du130w.dub130.mail.live.com
Not shown: 965 closed ports, 33 filtered ports
PORT    STATE SERVICE
80/tcp  open  http
443/tcp open  https

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 8.32 seconds
```

For mail submission to outlook.com use smtp-mail.outlook.com and port 25 or 587 (see [here](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/outlook/send-receive-from-app)).

Not sure if you can use a Gmail address to authenticate to Microsoft's mail service, though.

Comment: I have tried out this too but the error remains same

Comment: http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver
This link also isn't working too.

Comment: Make sure your credentials actually work on outlook.com.

Comment: Outlook.com only seems to like port 25 - even if it requires authentication.  If you're using a gmail address though then you probably need to use the gmail smtp server - smtp.gmail.com - and port 587